# Harddisk operations totally brings down my system respond time to its knees

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, performance, btrfs

I have massive system slowdowns during harddisk operations on my PC. My Firefox is responding slow, it gets to a extreme at times that it actually becomes a not responding program and greys out during web surfing while harddisk operates heavy. It only needs the simple copying of files to make my system slow.

I have a Gigabyte EP35DS3 with a Q6600, AHCI enabled in BIOS.

I have a LUKS encrypted btrfs formatted Western Digital Caviar Black 4TB disk where my Ubuntu runs on, as well as multiple other disks including a Western Digital Caviar Green with 2TB where 2 truecrypt partitions are on with my windows stuff.

I have my backup script running with `sudo ionice -c2 -n7 nice -n 19 rsync` and I am not sure if its actually working since I still feel it when its working.

Bitcoin-qt is totally thrashing my HDD and makes my PC almost unusable simply copying files in nautilus is annoying as well. I not really want to manually ionice every single programm I use. I not know why Ubuntu behaves this way and I hate to say it but windows does not have this problem and I don't think its because it runs on my slower disk.

Benchmarks show that the the speed is OK for my disks, but I always have this delay feeling, even when nothing is working on the HDD the response seems slow.

Is there something I can do? Even if I get I SSD, I wont have fun with it when my backups and other operations run on my disks and slow my entire system down.

Maybe drivers work differently and give the HDD operations to much priority by default or something?

Comment: Did you ever check the disk with smartctl from the smartmontools package?  Did you ever check top (NOT iotop) to see if your CPUs are maxed out?  Did you think encryption is free?

Comment: I did check my CPU of course and its not maxed out. And why should I think encryption is free? My CPU is not THAT old, it can handle the encryption very well. Even if it where eating up my CPU I expect my operation system to prioritize so I have no crazy slowdowns. Its the harddisk! I think this thing is called "blocking IO".  smartctl what I am supposed to use it for? Read the disks SMART data? I can do that with gnome-disk and the drive shows OK for everything.